# Cost of living index

Tags: macroeconomics, living-cost

Say you have a cost of living index based on the dollar for each state. 
Such as this one:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/chuckdevore/2019/08/06/when-is-a-dollar-not-a-dollar-states-and-the-cost-of-living/

Take Idaho's 92.3

Is this cost of living index an average or a mean based on each state?

Comment: "an average or a mean"? Did you mean to write median?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. I am trying to find what state is the exactly the national average, when it comes to the cost of living. Is it the state that is number 25 on this list or the state that is exactly 100 on the cost index.